# I can't post my question because the site thinks there is unformatted code in it

Tags: bug, code-formatting, markdown, editor, error-message

Below is a screenshot of my question along with the error preventing me from posting it. This is extraordinarily frustrating.
[image]

Comment: Probably because this is a question that looks like it should contain code, and you have markup that kind of looks like code. Honestly, I didn't know it had error messages for unformatted code. Frustrating for situations this, but that's certainly a step in the right direction.

Comment: This is just a guess, but the markup for your images may be causing problems. Having 3 images in a row like that is a little unusual. There are a lot of brackets (`[` and `]`) in there, not to mention the numbers and `+` sign. In other words, the "density" of symbols and numbers (as opposed to letters) is very high. Try breaking those up by adding some line breaks or captions, or just see if you can post it without the images, then add the images as an edit.

Comment: for the dupe voters that follow my vote: I can't repro this case and I already tried a few combinations but I'm pretty sure it must be the root cause.

Comment: @Katie would you be able to include the markup from that post in this question (use the citation option) or alternatively upload it somewhere, maybe in a gist on github? That relieves me from the effort to copy over your markdown from your screenshot. I need that so I can try to reproduce the issue you're having.

Comment: to echo what @rene says: if you still have the markup that is being problematic, it would be good to get it in text form so we can play with it in the debugger

Comment: Here is the text of the post: https://gist.github.com/kaitlynbrown/6e1fb254794431a3b739d7618e3442b2

Comment: I've updated the gist with multiple attempts to resolve the issue based on the comments made here and the post this one is marked as a duplicate of. I still can't get the error to go away.

Comment: update: I tried adding empty lines between the images and it worked. This is a shame though, because it would be a lot nicer to have the images show up next to one-another instead of being separated vertically

Answer (score 1):

The images you reference are cropped really small. What if you remove the hyperlinks to them entirely so you can inline the URLs? This dramatically reduces the number of square brackets that may be fooling the system into thinking those image links are unformatted code.

```
![GST+PST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7ypX.png)  
![GST Only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUOyi.png)  
![No Tax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEMYL.png)
```

Comment: Also, I personally don't think this should be necessary for a readable post but maybe you can placate the system further by marking up class names such as `ScrollView`, `ListView`, and `Grid`. I don't know if it actually identifies these as possible class names and if it actually requires them to be formatted as inline code (and if so, again, I personally disagree with that).

Comment: I also suspect the image markdown to be the culprit but for some reason I'm no longer able to trigger it, as I could on my proposed duplicate. I've tried a couple of other things from their post but I can't get it to bark. That check isn't rep-limited, right?

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work